# I have a problem "database is locked" when i try to parse channel_ids using their links

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, telegram, telethon

I try to parse id of channels only have their links. I use WITH construction for session in telethon and I think this could be my problem but I don't know.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.errors import ChannelInvalidError


def get_channel_id_sec(links):
    api_id = ''
    api_hash = ''

    with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        channel_ids = []
        for link in links:
            try:
                result = client(GetFullChannelRequest(link))
                channel_ids.append(result.chats[0].id)
            except ChannelInvalidError:
                print(f"Invalid channel: {link}")
        
        return channel_ids
```